# React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found

Tags: react-native, build, project, new-operator

I have created a new project called auth using react-native init auth at terminal.When i tried to run the project using react-native run-ios. The build failed and gave a error 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found.

Tried to update the react native version

react-native run-ios at terminal in mac

I expect the build to be successful and see the ios simulator 
The actual result which i got is build failed and hence cant see the simulator

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The issue is related to `cocoapods` dependency manager. Do the following to fix this:

1. Open the terminal and go to your project `ios` directory
2. Type in `pod init` (If it doesn't exist) and then `pod install`
3. Open the workspace project and delete the build from ios folder
4. Run `react-native run-ios` from terminal.

It should work now.

Comment: There is already podfile existing.when i try to run pod init, it says /usr/local/bin/pod: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: if already exist ignore pod init and just type "pod install" and it will take time to be finished, please don't forget to delete the build file from ios folder and then type react-native run-ios

Comment: did you type "pod install" ? It will overwrite the current one

Comment: @Vahid I have removed build folder and run pod install and try to build app. But it failed with the same error React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found in AppDelegate.h file

Comment: @sejn I have same issue, have you found any solution?

Comment: When I tried pod install I received that: `[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: cannot load such file -- /Users/rafael/workspace/everest-client-app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules.`

Comment: does not work at all, just tried on a fresh react-native project to add @react-navigation/native @react-navigation/native-stack non of the steps do help

Comment: In the `ios` dir, running `pod deintegrate && pod setup && pod install` (using Rosetta-mode iTerm2 for M1) usually fixes pod issues for me. This time, it did not.

Comment: I our case we've get same error in two Macs with M1 cpu, and the solution to run the App was through Xcode going to Product, Destination, Destination Architecture and choose Show Rosetta destination. After that, the error stay but the App start running in emulator.

Answer (score 14):

In my case the `libPods-FOO.a` library had somehow become unlinked when I did a `pod update && pod install`. To see if this applies to you:

1. In Xcode, check under Project Navigator:

   ```
   [Your Project Name] --> Targets --> [Your target name] --> General
   ```
2. Scroll down to `Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content`
3. If you don't have a `libPods-XXXX.a` in there (where XXXX is your project name) then add it:

   1. Click the '+' sign to add the libPods library
   2. Search for `libPods` in the search box
   3. Choose the `libPods-XXXX.a` and click `Add`.

[image: Add library]

[image: libPods.....a]

Comment: not getting this file, libPods-zzz.a ,any help?

Comment: @GaneshGodshelwar check for Pods-zzz.a

Comment: solved by adding this lines in podfile, as we were using env dev and pro
 abstract_target 'KidsCommonPods' do # <- Add this
  # React Native Maps dependencies
  target 'KidsDev' do
  end

  target 'KidsPro' do
  end

Answer (score 8):

Just a hint: for those of you using the M1 Macs, `pod install` won't work. You should use `arch -x86_64 pod install` as stated in [this issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10220)

Comment: My understanding is if you set your terminal app to use Rosetta mode, then `arch` is not needed.

Answer (score 7):

The issue happened due to the missing of React schema in cocoapods dependency. to resolve follow these steps:

1. open project in **XCode** using **ios/{project name}.xcworkspace** file
2. From menu bar -> click **Product-> Scheme -> Manage Scheme**
3. It will open a modal ->  click on the **+** button
4. List item
5. New modal -> In **target** DropDown select **React** and click okay
6. close the modal and rebuild project **Project - Build**

it will resolve the issue.

Comment: This worked for me. I also had an invalid import on <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h> and this solved the issue on M1 mac. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you . This solved the a lot of issue

Comment: I don't see React in the dropdown menu

Comment: I dont see React in Drop Down Menu

Comment: it worked for me using react native 0;70.6

Answer (score 5):

In case you have Mac with an Apple M1 chip, It can be resolve in two ways,

#SOLUTION 1

1. Open Application->Utilites->Terminal.app
2. Right-click, Terminal.app -> Get Info -> General-> Enable "Open using Rosetta"
3. Restart Terminal

[image]

#SOLUTION 2

1. From terminal execute

> sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

2. Go to iOS directory and execute

> arch -x86_64 pod install

Comment: In my case, this did not resolve the issue. I set both Xcode 13.3 and terminal to Rosetta mode. Xcode build fails regardless. I'm not 100% sure, yet, if my issue relates to this. Something else could be breaking that makes this error appear. Still investigating.

Answer (score 4):

In my Xcode project I had to have multiple targets.

[image]

I added the `(dev)` target for development purposes, but in order to add React Native to that target you have to add it to the Podfile.

```rb
target 'MyApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!

...

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  #  Add your target in the Podfile
  target 'MyApp (dev)' do
    inherit! :complete
  end

...
```

Then run `pod install` inside your *ios* folder, and done!

> **My setup:**
>
> react-native **0.70**, macOS Monterey, MacBook Pro M1 2021

Answer (score 2):

I did what @Vahid suggested, but I also had another issue. A set of instructions I was following told me to pull the related .xcodeproj file into my actual project and then manually link a few different files.

These steps were not necessary and were creating the issue for me.

I was following this:
https://github.com/frostney/react-native-ibeacon

But it's better to use this npm package and follow their instructions:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ibeacons

Answer (score 1):

follow this steps :

1. Select your project on Xcode
2. Go to Build Settings
3. In Search path tab select Header Search Path and add this values for both debug and release

   **$(inherited)**

   **${PODS_ROOT}**

   **${SRCROOT}/../../../ios/Pods/Headers** (Make sure to set it to recursive)

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! I switched from intel to M2 and my build was failing because the Header Search Path was empty

Comment: Edit: Don't use recursive as it may cause other build issues, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75930323/boost-library-compiler-errors-in-xcode

Answer (score 1):

It can happen if you are using mac on M1 chip and trying to run the app on a simulator. Try to install iterm2 from official site(https://iterm2.com/), and launch it with Rosetta(`Applications -> Right click on 'Iterm2' app -> "Get info" -> Check "Open using Rosetta"`). Then run:

1. `sudo gem install cocoapods`
2. `rm -rf /Users/{USERNAME}/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods`
3. Go to your project folder and run `cd ./ios && pod install`
4. Run build with `npx react-native run-ios`

Answer (score 1):

In this particular project, certain targets were not working. I noticed the broken targets with this error were missing libPods-myProjectName.a. Under Targets -> General tab, "Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content" I pressed the "+" icon and searched for "pods" and added "pods-myProjectName.a" and now it seems to work. This might not be applicable to you, but I am adding this as another possibility of what might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The simple pod install command did not work for me. If you have **M1 Mac** then try using.

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Answer (score 1):

For me adding `arm64` to Excluded Architectures section works.

[image]

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me after hours of searching.....why does this work?

Answer (score 1):

To those who are facing, make sure

```
  target 'runner' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for production
  end
  target 'runnerDev' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for development
  end
```

this is present for every flavor in Podfile

Answer (score 1):

if you are running the App in either M2 or M1 then you need to enable rosetta destination in xcode for your simulator. You can enable this from product -> Destination -> Destination Architecture -> show rosetta Architechture

Answer (score 0):

[Mac OSX]
I updated the cocoapods version
`brew upgrade cocoapods`

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue here and I fixed it just running `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` or you can just run `brew upgrade cocoapods` on macbook air M1. if cocoapods not is installed just install it running `sudo gem install cocoapods`.