# AppDelegate.h:8:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found #import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I recently added some targets to my React Native project in XCode 10.1

I am using React Native version 0.60.4

I was able to successfully add targets and run `pod install`, but then when I run `react-native run-ios`, I get the following build error:

```
AppDelegate.h:8:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

This answer did not work for me:
[React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916798/react-rctbridgedelegate-h-file-not-found)

The file does exist:

[image]

And the folder file path also exists in **Header Search Paths** in XCode.

[image]

I did notice React is missing here:

[image]

Could the above be the problem? Is it some configuration I am not doing in XCode?

This is my `Podfile`:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'DEV' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for DEV
  # pod 'AppCenter/Push', '~> 1.3.0'
  pod 'AppCenter/Crashes', '~> 2.0.1'
  pod 'AppCenter/Analytics', '~> 2.0.1'
  pod 'AppCenterReactNativeShared', '~> 2.0.0'

  # Pods for NFIBEngage
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-fishhook', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  target 'NFIBEngageTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end

target 'NFIBEngage-tvOS' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for NFIBEngage-tvOS



end

target 'PROD' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for PROD
  # pod 'AppCenter/Push', '~> 1.3.0'
  pod 'AppCenter/Crashes', '~> 2.0.1'
  pod 'AppCenter/Analytics', '~> 2.0.1'
  pod 'AppCenterReactNativeShared', '~> 2.0.0'

  # Pods for NFIBEngage
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-fishhook', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

end

target 'QA' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for QA
  # pod 'AppCenter/Push', '~> 1.3.0'
  pod 'AppCenter/Crashes', '~> 2.0.1'
  pod 'AppCenter/Analytics', '~> 2.0.1'
  pod 'AppCenterReactNativeShared', '~> 2.0.0'

  # Pods for NFIBEngage
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-fishhook', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

end

target 'UA' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for UA
  # pod 'AppCenter/Push', '~> 1.3.0'
  pod 'AppCenter/Crashes', '~> 2.0.1'
  pod 'AppCenter/Analytics', '~> 2.0.1'
  pod 'AppCenterReactNativeShared', '~> 2.0.0'

  # Pods for NFIBEngage
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-fishhook', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

end
```

Comment: can I see your podfile please

Comment: @GokulKulkarni, I added my `Podfile` above. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-react-native/issues/344#issuecomment-362354851 Have you tried this? @Daniel

Comment: @Daniel can u try by adding react dependency in the following way?
pod 'React', path: rn_path, subspecs: [
    'ART',
    'Core',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket',
    'DevSupport'
  ]

Comment: @GokulKulkarni, when I try your approach I get the following error, `[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined local variable or method `rn_path' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x007f9a624c48f8>.`

Comment: Declare the variable $rn_path='<path_to_your_react_native_node_module>'

Comment: got any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears the solution in this case for adding multiple targets was to use `abstract_target` which you can find in Cocoapods documentation, although it's not explicit that this is what it's for:

https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#abstract_target

So I needed some guidance on how exactly to apply this, which I got from **lifely** in this post:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4863#js-timeline-progressive-loader.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
#if __has_include(<React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>)
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#else
#import "RCTBridgeDelegate.h"
#endif
```

Comment: with the hash tags in front of them?

Comment: yes.. instead of #import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h> write whole content

Answer (score -1):

Simply navigate to iOS directory from terminal

first install pod by running below command:

```
pod install
```

and then run

```
run react-native run-ios
```