# Boost library compiler errors in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, boost

How do I correctly use boost with Xcode?

I'm trying to compile a project using the boost library. The example project compiles fine using GCC 12 in the terminal, but I can't get it to compile in Xcode. The compiler errors are mostly namespace problems within the boost library.
For example: `/boost_1_81_0/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath:11:11 No member named 'acos' in the global namespace`.
From that cmath file:

```
#ifndef __CMATH_HEADER
#define __CMATH_HEADER

#include <math.h>
namespace std {
using ::acos;
using ::cos;
using ::fmod;
using ::modf;
//...
}
#endif // CMATH_HEADER
```

I work on OSX 12.6.1 and use Xcode 14.2. The include paths are set to `/usr/local/boost/boost_1_81_0`.
I tried to compile with C++20 and C++17.
Other libraries including cmath (not from boost) work fine.

The example project in `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;
 
    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " " );
}
```

The compiler errors:

```
/usr/local/boost/boost_1_81_0/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath:11:11: error: no member named 'acos' in the global namespace
  using ::acos;
        ~~^
/usr/local/boost/boost_1_81_0/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath:12:11: error: no member named 'cos' in the global namespace
  using ::cos;
        ~~^
/usr/local/boost/boost_1_81_0/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath:13:11: error: no member named 'fmod' in the global namespace
  using ::fmod;
        ~~^
/usr/local/boost/boost_1_81_0/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath:14:11: error: no member named 'modf' in the global namespace
  using ::modf;
        ~~^
/usr/local/boost/boost_1_81_0/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath:15:11: error: no member named 'tan' in the global namespace
  using ::tan;
        ~~^
/usr/local/boost/boost_1_81_0/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath:16:11: error: no member named 'asin' in the global namespace
  using ::asin;
        ~~^
/usr/local/boost/boost_1_81_0/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath:17:11: error: no member named 'cosh' in the global namespace
  using ::cosh;
        ~~^
/usr/local/boost/boost_1_81_0/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath:18:11: error: no member named 'frexp' in the global namespace
  using ::frexp;
        ~~^
/usr/local/boost/boost_1_81_0/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath:19:11: error: no member named 'pow' in the global namespace
  using ::pow;
        ~~^
/usr/local/boost/boost_1_81_0/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath:20:11: error: no member named 'tanh' in the global namespace
  using ::tanh;
        ~~^
/usr/local/boost/boost_1_81_0/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath:21:11: error: no member named 'atan' in the global namespace
  using ::atan;
        ~~^
/usr/local/boost/boost_1_81_0/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath:22:11: error: no member named 'exp' in the global namespace
  using ::exp;
        ~~^
/usr/local/boost/boost_1_81_0/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath:23:11: error: no member named 'ldexp' in the global namespace
  using ::ldexp;
        ~~^
/usr/local/boost/boost_1_81_0/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath:24:11: error: no member named 'sin' in the global namespace
  using ::sin;
        ~~^
/usr/local/boost/boost_1_81_0/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath:25:11: error: no member named 'atan2' in the global namespace
  using ::atan2;
        ~~^
/usr/local/boost/boost_1_81_0/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath:26:11: error: no member named 'fabs' in the global namespace
  using ::fabs;
        ~~^
/usr/local/boost/boost_1_81_0/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath:27:11: error: no member named 'log' in the global namespace
  using ::log;
        ~~^
/usr/local/boost/boost_1_81_0/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath:28:11: error: no member named 'sinh' in the global namespace
  using ::sinh;
        ~~^
/usr/local/boost/boost_1_81_0/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath:29:11: error: no member named 'ceil' in the global namespace
  using ::ceil;
        ~~^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

Comment: your file compiles as is with `-I /opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.81.0_1/include`. Do you (or Xcode for you) specify other parameters on command line?

Comment: @AlexCohn Thank you so much. I somehow completely forgot to try compiling it via the terminal (without Xcode). Using gcc worked. Now it is clear that the problem is Xcode/my settings in Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what solved the problem, but it works now. I set the header include path in Xcode to: `/usr/local/boost/boost_1_81_0` (non-recursive). The recursive option might have been the source of all the errors. Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53088237/192373